# How is syscall restarted after sighandler returns in linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

This is a program1. When I type `CTRL+C`, it always restart syscall and block there.

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void sighandler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *ctx) {
}

int main() {
    stack_t s;
    s.ss_flags = 0;
    s.ss_size = 40000;
    s.ss_sp = malloc(40000);
    sigaltstack(&s, NULL);

    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_ONSTACK|SA_RESTART;

    sigfillset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    getchar();
}
```

However the program below, doesn't restart a syscall, it simply prints `哈哈` and exits.

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void restore_here() {
    printf("哈哈\n");
}

void sighandler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *ctx) {
    ucontext_t *sigctx = ctx;
    makecontext(ctx, restore_here, 0);
}

int main() {
    stack_t s;
    s.ss_flags = 0;
    s.ss_size = 40000;
    s.ss_sp = malloc(40000);
    sigaltstack(&s, NULL);

    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_ONSTACK|SA_RESTART;

    sigfillset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    getchar();
}
```

I know after my `sighandler` is returned, the c library will call `sigreturn` syscall to atomically set signal mask and do a jmp to the place specified in `ctx`. I wonder at what time does the core restart syscall? Why the latter one doesn't restart a syscall after `sigreturn` is called?

Comment: Why would passing an uninitialized context to makecontext in a signal handler be valid?

Comment: It isn't an unitialized context. It is the context of the receiving thread. You might be confused by the assignment to `sigctx` in the code, but that isn't actually used. Though it isn't safe either way.